# Get the sum of a Sum column in sql server 2012

Tags: sql-server-2012

I want to add a row and add the value of a sum column. . see below code. 
thanks

```
` SELECT 
             TicketSales.DeviceID AS [Device ID]
            ,COUNT(TicketSales.TicketID) AS [Total Issued Tickets]
            ,SUM(TicketSales.TotalPrice) AS [Total Amount]

            (Here I want to add row to get the sum of SUM(TicketSales.TotalPrice) As [Total Amount])

           FROM dbo.TicketSales
           WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, TicketSales.StartTime,101) BETWEEN '" & fromDate & "' AND '" & toDate & "'
           GROUP BY TicketSales.DeviceID`
```

Comment: Please post the code as text, not as image. You already have it as `SUM(TicketSales.TotalPrice)`, why isn't it working?

Comment: sorry, I updated my post.

Comment: i want to get the sum of the sum column

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try with a windowed `SUM()` with the actual `SUM()` from the `GROUP BY`.

```
SELECT 
    TicketSales.DeviceID AS [Device ID]
    ,COUNT(TicketSales.TicketID) AS [Total Issued Tickets]
    ,SUM(TicketSales.TotalPrice) AS [Total Amount]
    ,SUM(SUM(TicketSales.TotalPrice)) OVER()
FROM dbo.TicketSales
WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, TicketSales.StartTime,101) BETWEEN '" & fromDate & "' AND '" & toDate & "'
GROUP BY TicketSales.DeviceID`
```

The `OVER()` clause makes the outmost `SUM()` a windowed sum, so it can be applied with the grouped columns or aggregate results.

---

**EDIT**: If you want it as a row you need to `UNION` it.

```
;WITH Aggregates AS
(
    SELECT 
        TicketSales.DeviceID AS [Device ID]
        ,COUNT(TicketSales.TicketID) AS [Total Issued Tickets]
        ,SUM(TicketSales.TotalPrice) AS [Total Amount]
    FROM dbo.TicketSales
    WHERE CONVERT(VARCHAR, TicketSales.StartTime,101) BETWEEN '" & fromDate & "' AND '" & toDate & "'
    GROUP BY TicketSales.DeviceID`
)
SELECT
    A.[Device ID],
    A.[Total Issued Tickets],
    A.[Total Amount]
FROM
    Aggregates AS A
UNION ALL
SELECT
    [Device ID] = NULL,
    [Total Issued Tickets] = SUM(A.[Total Issued Tickets]),
    [Total Amount] = SUM(A.[Total Amount])
FROM
    Aggregates AS A
```

Comment: it worked ! thanks, but i want to add it as a row not as column, is it possible ?